# Exportar package.json en salida de webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

estoy teniendo un problema con mi configuración de webpack.

estoy teniendo varias entradas en mi archivo de configuración `webpack.production.js`
mi problema es que al generar el `build` todos vienen con extensión `.js`.

En una de mis entradas he agregado el `package.json` para que el output me sirva en `npm`.

```
entry: {
 index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
 package: './package.json',
}
...
output: {
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
}
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Como puedo hacer que mis archivos de salida mantengan la extensión?

```
webpack: 5.61.0 
webpack-cli: 4.9.1
```

Comment: Qué versión de webpack estás usando? :thinking_face:

Comment: 5.61.0 @joseglego

Comment: Pudiste probar la respuesta? @DoubleM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer de muchas maneras, la más sencilla sería usar npm para el proceso adicional (**ejemplo opción 1**). Ahora, si no puedes hacer esto, entonces puedes hacer uso de un plugin adicional en webpack `CopyWebpackPlugin` (**ejemplo opción 2**)

### Opción 1

Podrías hacerlo en 2 pasos:

1. El build con `webpack`
2. Copiar y pegar el `package.json` en el `dist` con `npm`

Sería algo así en tu package.json, la sección de `scripts`:

```js
{
  "bundle": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --output-file bundledFile.js",
  "copy": "cp package.json dist/",
  "build": "npm run bundle && npm run copy"
}
```

### Opción 2

Hay un plugin de Webpack que se llama CopyWebpackPlugin. Para poder usarlo debes configurarlo y agregarlo en tu `module.exports`

Instalarlo:

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Luego, en tu `webpack.config.js`

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

// ...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "./package.json", to: "package.json" },
      ],
    }),
  ]
}
```

Y listo. Ahora cuando hagas el build se copiará.

Comment: Necesito que sea en un solo paso

Comment: Vale, ahí te deje un nuevo ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en 1 paso :) espero te sirva! Me estás avisando! @DoubleM

Answer (score 0):

Un 'hack' para lograr esto podría ser que añadas un archivo `package.js` con el texto plano:

```javascript
require('../package.json')
```

y cambiar tu `webpack.config.js` con:

```javascript
    // ...
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
        package: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/package.js') // Archivo que importa el package.json
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]' // Para que se importe con el mismo nombre
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.json$/,
            type: 'asset/resource', // resolver el import como archivo estático
        }]
    }
    // ...
```

De esta manera engañas a webpack para que haga el traspaso del archivo a la carpeta de destino pensando en que parte del código *bundleado* la necesita